# Regex To Compare URLs for "functional equality"

Tags: javascript, html, regex, url

## The problem

I need to compare URL pathnames to determine if two browsers are viewing the same page. I am using `document.location.pathname` to get the pathname component of the URL and my problem is that this comparison must be very forgiving.

**Example 1:** Values of `document.location.pathname` that are considered "the same page":

```
1. /subfolder/index.html
2. /subfolder/
3. /subfolder
4. /subfolder/index.html?something=something#somewhere
```

**Example 2:** A second set of pathname values that are the same page, this time without a subfolder:

```
1. /
2. /index.html
3.
```

### Important Notes:

1. In the second example, #3 is literally nothing; the pathname may be nil, but the server will still add "index.html" while trying to resolve the resource specifier.
2. When a file is omitted from the URL, the page may be any `index.[something]` page. It could be index.php, index.aspx, index.html, index.htm, etc. `index.html` and `index.php` cannot match. Nor can `/somefolder/about.html` match `/somefolder`, although `/somefolder/index.php` could match `/somefolder`. (You get the idea).

---

## What I Need

I can write a massive chunk of JavaScript to do this, but I know there must be a nice, concise way to do it with RegEx. Googling turned up nothing but "how to match a URL pattern with Regex" junk, which is not too helpful.

I'm hoping someone fluent in RegEx can help. Thanks.

### NB:

Pure-JavaScript solutions only, please. No jQuery or other libraries; I don't have access to them in this scenario.

Comment: If index.html and index.php cannot match and both of them can be omitted, how do you know /path/ is NOT referring to /path/index.html and matches /path/index.php?

Comment: You're absolutely right about that possibility. But in my use-case, that's very, very unlikely. And, even if *does* occur, the result is not damaging based on what I'm doing. I'm not comparing random URLs on the internet; this is all part of an app (CodeKit) displaying local web projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following regex

```
\/((subfolder\/?(index\.\w+.*)?)|index\.\w+?)?$
```

And wrap it in a function

```
function isValid(url){
   var rgx = /\/((subfolder\/?(index\.\w+.*)?)|index\.\w+?)?$/;
   return url == "" || rgx.test(url);
}
```

The regex uses capturing groups and `|` operator meaning *or* and `?` to make the previous tokens optional. The last test case is handled without the use of regex.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/gI4bS8/1)

Just replace the `subfolder` in my regex to suit yours. And then its pretty simple to know if two paths are same

```
var areTwoPagesAreEqual = isValid("first path") == isValid("second path")
```

Comment: Thank you, but this Regex seems tied to the generic URL examples I gave. Those weren't real URLs; just illustrations. What I need is a function that takes two pathnames and tells me if they are the same page for ANY two pathnames; not just the example ones I listed.

Answer (score 0):

All your scenarios are matched with

```
var regex = /^\/subfolder\/?(?:index\.html(?:.*)?)?$/
```